# Use regex to detect URLs | knockout js

Tags: javascript, regex, knockout.js

I'm currently editing a project where the front end is largely written in Javascript and `knockout,js`.  Right now I'm trying to detect URLs in the text and turn them into links.  Doing a quick stack overflow search, I found that in Javascript, the following function will do this for me:

```
var replaceURLWithHTMLLinks = function(text) {
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
};
```

However, I can't figure out how to implement this with knockout. Another quick search showed that a lot of people use regex with knockout with the .extend() function like

```
this.foo = ko.observable().extend(<function>)
```

where `<function>` is their regex function.  The regex in these examples isn't as detailed though, and I'm trying to figure out how to implement the URL detecting function as a knockout `extend`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can just use the `replaceURLWithHTMLLinks`, as long as you call it somewhere in your code.  This will actually do the replacement.

The Knockout `extend` method provides the ability to do validations on your data.  For instance, if you have an input field that requires a specific format or other validation, you can use `extend` to validate that your phone numbers and dates are properly formatted, and that your numeric fields have only numbers in them.

`extend` is completely different from what you're trying to do, so you an skip that part, entirely for this purpose.

Just call the `replaceURLWithHTMLLinks` directly from within your Javascript, and you should be done.